# ConfigParser not working in root user

Tags: python, ubuntu, nginx

So i wrote a python program that work on nginx log.

I made a path.config file

```
[path]
value =/var/log/myProject/access_log
```

The log path is correct and its fine.
And inside my python script i did

```
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
CONFIG_FILE = SafeConfigParser()
CONFIG_FILE.read('path.config')
file_path = CONFIG_FILE.get("path", "value")
```

When i ran this as normal user it showed no problem. But when i switch to root user and try to ran this then an error pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/docs/myscript.py", line 18, in <module>
    file_path = CONFIG_FILE.get("path", "value")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 607, in get
    raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'path'
```

Is this any permission problem with root user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your code, it should work with the root account if:

- path.config and your script are in the same directory
- the script is run in the directory.

I mean:

```
root@hostname:/tmp# cd your_dir/
root@hostname:/tmp/your_dir# ls
path.config  script.py
root@hostname:/tmp/your_dir# python script.py
```